# Confirmation of Hadith

Tags: hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

Is this true that Holy Prophet Muhammad SAW said “When I command you to do anything, do of it as much as you possibly can".

Comment: Your question title and question text are in clear contradiction

Answer (score 1):

This is the actual Hadith:

> Abu Huraira reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him,
> said, “What I have prohibited for you, avoid it. What I have commanded
> you, **do it as much as you can**. Verily, those before you were
> ruined only due to their excessive questioning and contradicting their
> prophets.”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 7288, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 1337